# GNOME 3 - bottom panel is hiding - how to unhide it or change behaviour

Tags: gnome3, debugging, gnome-panel

After upgrading Debian Wheezy to Jessie, I experience some random unhiding behaviour of the bottom panel. It does not appear - as before - by moving the mouse into lower right corner. It seems it is showing up, when you move the mouse in the middle of the bottom... but only in 1 out of 15 cases...

- How is the right way to unhide (is ticking enough or does keeping the mouse there for a few seconds help ... and where)?
- Are there ways to change the behaviour?

Current Gnome version is 3.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving mouse to bottom of the screen is usually enough to show bottom panel. Just move the mouse to bottom and a little bit more down ;) I know, sometimes it doesn't work for the first time. Second way is to use keyboard shortcut – `windows key (left to the left alt) + m`. Panel is not supposed to hide automatically, so clicking away from it's area or another wk+m will hide it.

Comment: wow! thx... hard to guess that mouse movement... :)